# How to center an inline element within a block element using CSS?

Tags: html, css, center

I'm trying to center an inline element (span, for instance) within a fixed-width block element, so that the contained inline element determines how the text is laid out in the block element.
 Like this:

```css
        .container {
            width: 200px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .centered {
            /* PLACE THIS AS THE CENTER (HORIZONTALLY) OF THE CONTAINER DIV */
        }
```

```html
       <div class='container'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ullum latine vituperatoribus sed ad, ut sit nihil sententiae. Ad minim prodesset eum, mei ei <span class='centered'>dicam</span> facete accusata, sea nonumy postulant ut. No fabellas facilisis mel, iriure constituto constituam vix te. </div>
```

Here is an idea of what I'm looking for:
[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Honestly, I doubt this is possible (except maybe with some javascript hack). You would be better off centering it yourself (maybe with percentages)

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are expecting. Could you add a image of the desired result?

Comment: Since you have `white-space: no-wrap` your full content won't be visible.Can you please describe bit more about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: please explain what do you want(maybe some image)

Comment: Remove `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: I am not sure if there is any way in CSS to achieve this. You can use jQuery.

Comment: Is this what you want? - https://jsfiddle.net/cx8u7hez/1/

Comment: @LuísP.A., yes, but dynamic so it can by done programatically.

Comment: This is not possible with css alone - it cannot tell you where a span is and the centre based on it

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
        margin-left: 500px;
        width: 200px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: scroll;

           }
.centered {
            /* PLACE THIS AS THE CENTER (HORIZONTALLY) OF THE CONTAINER DIV */
          }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution if you are placing the `.centered` tag exactly center to the `.container` div the HTML code.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.centered {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ullum latine vituperatoribus sed ad, ut sit nihil sententiae. Ad minim prodesset eum <span class='centered'>dicam</span> mei ei facete accusata, sea nonumy postulant ut. No fabellas facilisis mel, iriure constituto constituam vix te. 
</div>
```

Note: It will work only if the `.centered` is actually the center element in HTML.

Check the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63rk42Ln/)